# How to properly read the url of attachments from messages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want it to read when someone sends an image or sends a link of an image like with Imgur and then log the attachments url to a channel.

I have tried using `if(message.attachments.length > 0 || message.content.includes(message.attachments))` but that seemed to do absolutely nothing. I looked on the discord.js and it says that MessageAttachments is a collection of all attachments in one single message so I attempted to resolve it and then let it output the collection into a message but that also seemed to do nothing as well. No errors or anything.

This is my full code for when someone sends an image.

```
if(message.attachments.length > 0 || message.content.includes(message.attachments)){

 var promise1 = Promise.resolve(message.attachments);

 promise1.then(function(value) {
  client.channels.find("name","picture-log").send(value) 
 });

 //var att = new MessageAttachment();
 //client.channels.find("name","picture-log").send(`${message.author.tag} sent an embed of` + att.url) 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well `message.attachments` does indeed return pictures or files, but **only** the ones uploaded to Discord directly.
So if you want to filter URLs you need to use the `message.content`, and find the links with regex or something like that.
I tried to make a regex for this (might not be perfect but should work):

```js
function imgurLinks (message) {
  return message.match(/https?:\/\/(www.|i.|)imgur\.com[^\s]+/g);
}
var links = imgurLinks("hey take a look at this: https://i.imgur.com/ecSWPgA.png");
console.log(links);
```

That function returns an array of imgur links, from there just see how many links there are (if any) and do something if there are.

```
client.channels.find("name","picture-log")
    .send(`${message.author.tag} sent imgur links: ${links.join(" ")}`)
```